# Showing that a subset is dense in a separable metric space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Is there any general "mechanism" or rule-of-thumb to show that a subset of a metric space $(M,d)$ is dense. For example I am currently trying to digest the proof for:

$M$ satisfies second axiom of countability $\implies$ $M$ is separable

> Let $(B_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable base for $M$ and choose
>   $a_n ∈ B_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. We only need to show that $A = \{a_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $M$. Given any non-empty open set $O$ and $x ∈ O$, there
>   exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x ∈ B_n ⊆ O$ by definition of base. Consequently,
>   $a_n ∈ O$ and $A ∩ O \neq ∅$ follows

In what way is this proving density of $A$?

Comment: A set is dense in a metric space if the closure of that set is the whole space, so showing that $\bar{A}=M$ shows that $A$ is dense.

Comment: Another way to show that a set is dense, is to prove that it intersect with every open subset. (i.e for every open set $U$, $A\cap U \not = \emptyset$)

Comment: So as an analogy proving $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$ would show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Jepsilon yes exactly

Comment: @yanko So that is why he is using the $O$ subsets, yes? However can $O$ be any arbitrary open set containing any number of points from $A$?

Comment: In fact we do not assume that $O$ contains any points from $A$, only that $O$ is open. We show that it must contain points from $A$ using the definition of basis. Since $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a basis the open set $O$ must contain a set $B_n$ and since it contains this set it must also contain a point $a_n$ from $A$ because of how $A$ is defined. Just like how we can always find a sequence of rational numbers that converge to a real number for any real number, we can find a sequence of points in $A$ that converge to a point $x$ for any $x\in M$.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Ok this comment really cleared the picture. So is this strategy worth trying in any scenario? that is, 

Define open $O$, 

$O$ must contain a $B_n$ by definition of the base, 

$B_n$ must contain some $a_n$, 

Therefore $a_n \in O$

Comment: Not in any scenario necessarily, we use it here because of the second countability. Without this, the basis of open sets might not be countable. Why do we need countability of the basis? It is precisely this property which allows us to construct a sequence of points (sequences must be countable) instead of a net (ugly). Separable means that you have a COUNTABLE dense subset, so without the second countability assumption we cannot make this argument, we can still show that $O$ will contain a set from the basis and we can construct a set like $A$, but it will not be countable necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $A$ is dense in a metric space $M$ if every point $x\in M$ either belongs to $A$ or is a limit point of $A$. For $x$ to be a limit point of $A$ means that every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point from $A$ other than $x$ itself. So, by considering an arbitrary nonempty open set $O$ and showing that $A\cap O\neq \emptyset$ we are showing that all nieghborhoods of any point not in $A$ contain a point from $A$, i.e. all points are limit points and thus $\bar{A}=M$.